# Migrating from NewtonSoft.Json to System.Text.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, system.text.json, asp.net-apicontroller

We have an POST endpoint which accepts dictionary as request body.

```
        public class A {
public IDictionary<string, JsonElement?>? Values { get; set; };
    }
```

Earlier we were accepting JToken. We have replaced JToken with JsonElement during migration.

The request body is as below

```
{"tags": {
    "Some-tag": "Tags-value"
  }
}
```

It was working seamlessly when it was JToken. After migration, I am getting error "Error converting value "Tags-value" to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Text.Json.JsonElement]"

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Last paragraph in this section may be of interest to you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#jsonelement-is-a-union-struct _"Starting in .NET 6, you can use JsonNode type and types in the System.Text.Json.Nodes namespace that correspond to JObject,JArray, and JToken."_

Comment: Can you please add an [mre]?

Comment: Why `JsonElement?` and not `JsonElement`?

Comment: The name of the property `Values` does not correspond to the name in the JSON `"tags"`.  But if I fix that e.g. by adding `[JsonPropertyName("tags")]` to `Values` then I cannot reproduce your problem in .NET 6, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/YRczg4.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].  (Maybe you are using an earlier version of .NET?)

Answer (score 0):

This is configurable when deserializing or serializing. Maybe you need other options too.

```
     public static readonly JsonSerializerOptions SettingsOptions = new()
            {
                NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString,
                UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonElement
            };
```

Then you can use this option like this:

```
 Data example = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(content, JsonSerializerConfig.SettingsOptions);
```